# How to playlay multiple Particle Systems when colliding with multiple obstacles using object pooling?

Tags: unity, c#, particles

I have two types of particle, one for each player:

1. Player 1 (Red Particle)
2. Player 2 (Blue Particle)

When player 1 collides with an obstacle then I want to play the red particle system, and when player 2 collides with an obstacle then I want to play the blue particle system.

Code:

TouchControll.cs

```
 public GameObject PlayersPartical;        

  void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)  //here my player collided with obstacle
    {
        foreach (Transform child in transform)
        {
            if (child.tag == "point")
            {

                //GameObject partical = Instantiate(twopartical[Random.Range(0,1)], transform.position, transform.rotation); 
                //ParticleSystem heal = partical.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
                //heal.Play();
                GameObject partical = Instantiate(PlayersPartical, transform.position, transform.rotation);
                ParticleSystem heal = partical.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
                heal.Play();

                ObjectPooler.Instance.SpawnFromPool("redandbluepartical", transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }
     }

ObjectPooler.cs

    public static ObjectPooler Instance;

    public void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class Pool                 
    {
        public string tag;
        public GameObject prefab1;
        public GameObject prefab2;
        public int size;
    }

    public List<Pool> pools; 

    public Dictionary<string, Queue<GameObject>> pooldictionary;//which gameobject you should be pool

    void Start () {

        pooldictionary = new Dictionary<string, Queue<GameObject>>();  

        foreach(Pool pool in pools) //add a pool in list
        {
            Queue<GameObject> objectpool = new Queue<GameObject>();

            for(int i=0;i<pool.size;i++)
            {
                GameObject obj =  Instantiate(pool.prefab1);
                GameObject obj1 = Instantiate(pool.prefab2);
                obj.SetActive(false);
                obj1.SetActive(false);

                //objectpool.Enqueue(obj);
            }

            pooldictionary.Add(pool.tag, objectpool);
        }
    }

   public GameObject SpawnFromPool(string tag,Vector3 position,Quaternion rotation)  //two tag red and blue partical
    {
        if(!pooldictionary.ContainsKey(tag))
        {
            Debug.Log("doesnot exist" + tag);
            return null;
        }

        GameObject objecttospawn =  pooldictionary[tag].Dequeue();

        //here how to call my trigger

        objecttospawn.SetActive(true);
        objecttospawn.transform.position = position; //pos
        objecttospawn.transform.rotation = rotation; //rotation

        pooldictionary[tag].Enqueue(objecttospawn);
        return objecttospawn; 
    }
```

Image1:

[image]

Image2:

[image]

How do I call these particles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your new question: 
I've changed the pooling system to new one. this one is not generic but I've written it spacial for your case:

Pooling.CS

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public enum PlayerColor
{
    Blue,
    Red
};

public class Pooling : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Pooling Instance;

    [Header("Particles systems")]
    public GameObject particleObject;

    [Header("Particles systems Materials"), Space(10)]
    public Material greenMaterial;
    public Material redMaterial;

    private List<ParticleSystem> particlesList;
    private ParticleSystemRenderer redrer;

    public void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;
        particlesList = new List<ParticleSystem>();
    }

    public void PlayParticleFromPool(PlayerColor color, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation)
    {
        if (particlesList.Count < 1)
        {
            GameObject firstParticleObject = Instantiate(particleObject, position, rotation);
            particlesList.Add(firstParticleObject.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>());
            firstParticleObject.transform.parent = transform;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < particlesList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!particlesList[i].isPlaying)
            {
                redrer = particlesList[i].GetComponent<ParticleSystemRenderer>();
                switch (color)
                {
                    case PlayerColor.Blue:
                        redrer.material = greenMaterial;
                        break;
                    default:
                        redrer.material = redMaterial;
                        break;
                }

                particlesList[i].Play();
                return;
            }
        }

        GameObject newParticleObject = Instantiate(particleObject, position, rotation);
        newParticleObject.transform.parent = transform;
        particlesList.Add(newParticleObject.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>());
        redrer = newParticleObject.GetComponent<ParticleSystemRenderer>();
        switch (color)
        {
            case PlayerColor.Blue:
                redrer.material = greenMaterial;
                break;
            default:
                redrer.material = redMaterial;
                break;
        }
        newParticleObject.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().Play();
    }
}
```

And I simplified the player script to satisfy this new Pooling system, Replace Old Code with this:

```
public PlayerColor playerColor;

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)  //here my player collided with obstacle
    {
        Pooling.Instance.PlayParticleFromPool(playerColor, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
```

Step By Step Guide How to use these scripts:

1. Replace Your Old Pooling system with new one.
2. Create "Empty Object" and assign the new Pooling script to it.
3. Now Create Two Material One for Red Player and another for Blue Player.
4. Setup Blue particle system Material like this: assign texture for blue particles.
   [image]
5. Setup Red particle system Material like this: assign texture for red particles
   [image]
6. Now Change Player Color like this:

   [image]

7.Select Blue for blue player and select Red for red Player.

8. At last step set you pooling like this:

[image]

I Hope this will work. I've tested it and it did worked for me.

Comment: thanks for answer but the problem is always playing blue particle. when red player touch obstacle then plays a blue particle and when a blue player touch obstacle then plays a blue particle. see this: https://imgur.com/a/1x5N5Gi

Comment: Have you changed player color as i mentioned in setp 6. I checked it and it is working.

Comment: can u notice my player game object store the script(TouchControll.cs)?

 how to set step number seven I have only one script.

Comment: You have two players Right and each player has there own player has there own script. so each player setup the color.

Comment: Ahh you made the two player child of the single parent. and that's why are always getting blue particles..

Comment: exactly see image:https://imgur.com/a/VSE3GdU

Comment: And you are using "onTriggerEnter" on the parent. solution to this is create two scripts for each player and each of the script will only manag there own collision. so that way that way you could differentiate between the two players.

Comment: There is no way you can differentiate between the two players with only script on the parent. you have to separate the collision scripts for each player.

Comment: Solution to you problem: Create a script for player collision and assign that script to both of the players and remove the collision code from parent script. code for that i  have posted in my answer called "Player script". just copy that and past that code into the new script you have created and then from unity change player color and voila that's it.

Comment: thanks for the help and give your valuable time. can u explain plz `if(particlesList.Count < 1)` i m not understand this if condition. why?? thanks for your big help.

Comment: "particlesList" is list of "ParticleSystem" which hold all of the "ParticleSystem" instantiated by pooled system. Now "if(particlesList.Count < 1)" mean that if our "particlesList" has no "ParticleSystem " then its means we need to create new "ParticleSystem " and assign it to the list.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know with whom this script is attached but I would say this job should be done by player itself and my way of doing this will be like this:

```
public GameObject playerPartical;

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    GameObject particalObject = Instantiate(playerPartical, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    ParticleSystem partical = particalObject.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
    partical.Play();
}
```

As this will be attached to each player then "player 1" will get reference to Red particles and "player 2" will get reference to "Blue particles". Now by this way each player will be only responsible for themselves.

But the best possible solution wold to [Object pooling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tdSmKaJvCoA). 
As i don't know much about your game so i would stop here and if you have any question please let me know.

Comment: this code attach to the player. can u give tips for how to work partical with objectpooling.

Comment: I have linked video to object pooling you can learn all about object pooling from there. to visit the video click on the Object pooling in answer section.

Comment: Also try the code I've posted.

Comment: each player will be only responsible for themselves exactly.

Comment: From that statement i mean player don't have to find which particle should i play. As each player knows  about themselves.

Comment: If it resolved your problem also accept the answer.

Comment: which game object i store in Playerspartical(can i create parent gameobject and then stored a child object as red and blue gameobject ???) and how to call my trigger when my player collide with obstacle??i made some changes in my script

Comment: Nice you have updated your question and you implemented the pool system. I will re_answer your question in a little while.

Comment: I hope you my question is to understand??